# A more elegant way to concatenate C strings in C++?

Tags: c++, concatenation, cstring, strcpy, strcat

I was wondering if there was a less....listy way to do this? I have an assignment that puts credit card information in a UDP packet, with the information separated in the buffer by colons, so that it looks like `Bob Jones:7845 6133 7889 4425:09/2017:654.99` stored in a single character array.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char buffer[256];
    char name[64];
    char cardNum[32];
    char expiration[8];
    char amount[14];

    while(true)
    {
        /*********
        (Input prompts go here, break if user types quit)
        *********/

        strcpy(buffer, amount);
        int length = strlen(buffer);
        buffer[length] = ':';
        strcat(buffer, cardNum);
        length = strlen(buffer);
        buffer[length] = ':';
        strcat(buffer, name);
        length = strlen(buffer);
        buffer[length] = ':';
        strcat(buffer, expiration);

        /***************
        (run all of the networking code)
        ***************/
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I have to ask, why use C strings at all?

Comment: Simple std::string concatenation: `std::string(amount) + ':' + cardNum + ':' + name + ':' + expiration`

Comment: We are using C functions that require C strings in a larger C++ program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++, you can concatenate `std::string` objects using `+`, or append to a [string stream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream).

In both C and C++ you have access to formatted output, which I think is preferred here, because the whole code fits neatly on a single line:

```
sprintf(buffer, "%s:%s:%s:%s", amount, cardNum, name, expiration);
```

Comment: Yes! Brilliant! I wanted to use formatted output to do this, but wasn't sure what was the best way. This is exactly within that line of thinking, thank you.

Comment: use `snprintf` to avoid a buffer overflow.